# What is the callback URL for in SSO?

Tags: callback, single-sign-on

sorry i don't know what is the purpose of the callback URL in most SSO context. Could someone please give me some tips, like why is the callback URL necessary, what it is used for, and what should i do in the callback URL. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the page that the user is returned to after he logs in.

Example: You want to post a comment on a news page, but the website won't let you do it until you log in.  After you log in, it returns you to the page so that you can post your comment.

Comment: Question: Is it because HTTP is stateless, and the authentication method is HTTP and that is why a callback URL is necessary to act on upon authentication completion?

Comment: The callback URL doesn't have anything to do with authentication (other than, when the user is redirected to that URL, they are redirected as an authenticated user).